# Jupyter Notebook Error: "Jupyter command `jupyter-notebook` not found."

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

[image]

I just downloaded vscode using homebrew and install python@3.11 using homebrew as well. I used pip3 install jupyter as I saw other recommend to fix this issue and still no luck. I have downloaded all the extensions on vscode and I have set the kernal to homebrew version of python and I still recieve this issue. Note that I have used notebooks in the past and have never gotten this issue so I am not really sure what it is this time. I have not installed anaconda.

I have tried uninstalling and installing the extensions but no luck. I have tried to pip3 uninstall jupyter, pip3 uninstall notebook and reinstall them and still no luck. I have tried to change the kernal to the default python3 on the mac and still nothing. My mac is m1 running on Ventura 13.2. I am able to run python code on regular python files just not using jupyter notebook. I followed the instructions how to set it up on vscode website but I got this error.

Comment: run 'jupyter notebook' on a terminal and check whether it works

Comment: after running that command, it says "zsh: command not found: jupyter"

Comment: what about "python3 -m notebook"

Comment: yes it works. It opens a tab in my browser and I actually tried running the .ipynb file and it works

Answer (score 17):

I have same issue using VSCode on Mac OS.

VSCode's 'Jupyter' plugin is broken, causing VSCode unable to bind with python interpreter. Downgrading from `v2023.1.2000312134` to `v2022.11.1003412109` fixed my issue.

[image: Downgrade to the previous version]

Comment: The bug identified in version `v2023.1.2000312134` is tracked here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/12726

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue, running on m1 mac (Ventura 13.2). If you aren't already, make sure you are utilising a python virtual environment:

```
# Create a python virtual environment
$ python -m venv venv
# Activate your python virtual environment
$ source venv/bin/activate
```

Form your VSCode Command Palette (Shift+Command+P), search and then choose

> Jupyter: Select Interpreter to Start Jupyter Server

You should then select the python version that is associated to your virtual environment (venv).

Answer (score 4):

I have a very similar set-up to yours, and the same issue was driving me nuts. The fix was very straightforward, though, just make sure to do the two following steps:

- On VS Code's Command Palette search for and click on "Jupyter: Select Interpreter to Start Jupyter Server", and then select the interpreter to coincide to the one you're using for Python and where you know you can work with Jupyter.
- To double-check, with your .ipynb file open you should see the chosen environment on the top right selector. If it isn't, then make sure to select it there as well.

If VS Code recommends installing Jupyter click accept and do so as well.

Finally, I would recommend you check out [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/docs/basic-usage/) instead for managing both package dependencies as well as virtual environments. I find it makes the whole workflow more tidy.

[image: VS Code on Mac OS Command Palette screenshot]

[image: Top-right VS Code window screenshot of an .ipynb file]

Comment: The key for me was the "Jupyter: Select Interpreter to Start Jupyter Server". Even though the ipynb file said it was using the venv environment, it wasn't starting that one (I guess). The command palette step fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue, in my case:

what helped me -> I did a VS code update, restarted the VS code.